# Shape Size? Extend Script After Effects

Tags: jsx, extendscript, after-effects

Have tried many ready-made solutions and don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I want to set the size of the ellipse, but the line with setting the size gives an error.

```
var shapeLayer = myComp.layers.addShape();
var mask = shapeLayer.property("ADBE Root Vectors Group").addProperty("ADBE Vector Shape - Ellipse");
mask.property("ADBE Vector Ellipse Size").setValue([300, 300]);
```

Comment: what error? What do you see in the debug console if you type in `smask.property("ADBE Vector Ellipse Size")`